# Returning from function on failure

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am writing my back end with node js, and as I am fairly new to node and its asynchronous nature, I need a clarification. What I am trying to achieve is to return from a middleware function if and when authentication fails. I was able to do it by just using a `return;` after every condition, but this way I had to set some values for the res object for every condition I had. For instance:

```
if(recvToken) {
    try {
      let tokenVal = jwt.decode(recvToken, app.get('jwtToken'));
      if(tokenVal.exp < Date.now()) {
        res.status(401).json({
          success: false,
          message: 'Auth failed',
          details: 'Some other details'
          // And a few more fields
        });
      }
      else if(tokenVal.mode !== 'cust') {
        res.status(401).json({
          success: false,
          message: 'Auth failed',
          details: 'Some other details'
          // And a few more fields
        });
      }
      else {
        // A few more conditions, you get the gist
      }
    }
    catch (err) {
      return;
    }
  }
  else {
    return;
  }
```

This works, right. But I would like to have a function that handles all these failures for me. I messed around a bit and ended up with something:

```
function handleFailure(res, cb) {
  res.status(401).json({
    message: 'Not authorized'
  });
  cb();
}
```

Which is called from all the conditional code, like:

```
if(tokenVal.mode !== 'cust') {
  handleFailure(res, function() { return; });
}
else if(tokenVal.exp < Date.now()) {
  handleFailure(res, function() { return; });
}
```

Sure it looks cleaner, but it doesn't work because the return in callback function returns from the callback function and not the parent function. 
Is there anything of this sort I can do to return from the function that calls handleFailure? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you need to pass a callback to `handleFailure`? Since it's all synchronous you could just return.

Comment: @schroffl Is there no possibility of returning from the function without having the res object set? If none, I feel stupid for asking this question...

Comment: What do you mean with "without having the res object set"? If I interpret your question correctly: you can just return before calling `res.status` or wrap everything in an if-statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be to make **handleFailure** not require a callback.

```
function handleFailure(res) {
  res.status(401).json({
    message: 'Not authorized'
  });
}

// Somewhere else in the code
if(tokenVal.mode !== 'cust') {
  handleFailure(res);
  return;
}
else if(tokenVal.exp < Date.now()) {
  handleFailure(res);
  return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Both the answers make sense and they both work because they essentially do the same thing. Realized that I don't even need a callback!

Comment: Jonty was a few seconds faster :P

Yeah they do the same, since `handleFailure` returns undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You could return the `handleFailure` function, so the execution of the current function ends and at the same time you are handling the failure (sending back the 401 response).

```
function handleFailure(res) {
  res.status(401).json({
    message: 'Not authorized'
  });
}

if(tokenVal.mode !== 'cust') {
  return handleFailure(res);
}
else if(tokenVal.exp < Date.now()) {
  return handleFailure(res);
}
```